# how to hold values in listview on next previous button?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, listview

I am developing an application which uses `ListView` to display questions and it's options from different tables from `DataBase`.
I have assign `PageSize="1"` in `DataPager` so that only one question should display at a time, after choosing option user clicks on Next button which shows the other question but if user clicks on Previous button the `ListView` is not showing the previous selected option?
I don't know how to hold the previous selected option as i have to submit them in `DataBase` in last.

Comment: I guess what you need is to preserve the values of your controls between page post backs, without saving them to the database. Is it correct?

Comment: Please add the relevant code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can preserve the controls' values in a `Hashtable` in the `Session`. Below is a sample page which renders 2 `TextBox` controls and a `CheckBox` for each item in the `ListView`. The state is preserved between paging events.

The `WebForm1.aspx` page:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication13.WebForm1" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:ListView runat="server" ID="listView" EnableViewState="true" OnItemDataBound="listView_ItemDataBound" ClientIDMode="Inherit">

                <ItemTemplate>
                    <div class="Product">
                        <strong>
                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TextBoxId" OnTextChanged="TextBox_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
                            ::
                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TextBoxName" OnTextChanged="TextBox_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
                        </strong>
                        <br />
                        <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="CheckBoxChecked" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="CheckBoxChecked_CheckedChanged" />
                    </div>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <LayoutTemplate>
                    <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="itemPlaceholder"></asp:PlaceHolder>
                </LayoutTemplate>
                <ItemSeparatorTemplate>
                    <hr />
                </ItemSeparatorTemplate>
            </asp:ListView>

            <asp:DataPager ID="DataPagerProducts" runat="server" PagedControlID="listView"
                PageSize="1" OnPreRender="DataPagerProducts_PreRender">
                <Fields>
                    <asp:NextPreviousPagerField ShowFirstPageButton="True" ShowNextPageButton="False" />
                    <asp:NumericPagerField />
                    <asp:NextPreviousPagerField ShowLastPageButton="True" ShowPreviousPageButton="False" />
                </Fields>
            </asp:DataPager>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The code behind file - `WebForm1.aspx.cs`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace WebApplication13
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// This object will preserve the values of the controls
        /// </summary>
        internal Hashtable DataObject
        {
            get
            {
                if (Session["DataObject"] == null)
                    Session["DataObject"] = new Hashtable();
                return (Hashtable)Session["DataObject"];
            }
            set
            {
                Session["DataObject"] = value;
            }
        }
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
                BindData();
        }

        private void BindData()
        {
            listView.DataSource = new[] { 
                    new{Id=1,Name="test 1",Checked=true},
                    new{Id=2,Name="test 2",Checked=true},
                    new{Id=3,Name="test 3",Checked=true}
                };
            listView.DataBind();
        }

        protected void DataPagerProducts_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            BindData();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Use the ItemDataBound event to set the values of the controls
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        protected void listView_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
        {
            SetValue("TextBoxId", "Id", e);
            SetValue("TextBoxName", "Name", e);
            SetValue("CheckBoxChecked", "Checked", e);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Sets the value of the control with the specified id by looking in the user session's DataObject hashtable
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="id">The id of the searched control</param>
        /// <param name="dataProperty">The property name of the data item</param>
        /// <param name="e">The list view item event arguments</param>
        void SetValue(string id, string dataProperty, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Item.DataItem == null)
                return;
            var webControl = e.Item.FindControl(id);
            switch (webControl.GetType().ToString())
            {
                //To do: handle other control types, such as System.Web.UI.WebControls.ComboBox etc.
                case "System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox":
                    var label = (TextBox)webControl;
                    if (DataObject[label.ClientID + e.Item.DataItemIndex.ToString()] == null)
                    {
                        DataObject[label.ClientID + e.Item.DataItemIndex.ToString()] = e.Item.DataItem.GetType().GetProperty(dataProperty).GetValue(e.Item.DataItem);
                    }
                    label.Text = String.Format("{0}", DataObject[label.ClientID + e.Item.DataItemIndex.ToString()]);
                    break;
                case "System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBox":
                    var checkBox = (CheckBox)webControl;
                    if (DataObject[checkBox.ClientID + e.Item.DataItemIndex.ToString()] == null)
                    {
                        DataObject[checkBox.ClientID + e.Item.DataItemIndex.ToString()] = e.Item.DataItem.GetType().GetProperty(dataProperty).GetValue(e.Item.DataItem);
                    }
                    checkBox.Checked = (bool)DataObject[checkBox.ClientID + e.Item.DataItemIndex.ToString()];
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }

        protected void CheckBoxChecked_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var checkBox = (CheckBox)sender;
            DataObject[checkBox.ClientID + (((ListViewDataItem)((Control)sender).Parent)).DataItemIndex] = checkBox.Checked;
        }

        protected void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var textBox = (TextBox)sender;
            DataObject[textBox.ClientID + (((ListViewDataItem)((Control)sender).Parent)).DataItemIndex] = textBox.Text;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To preserve the values in such scenerios, use Session object. You can create a collection of values such that - Question Id, Answer Id etc and store it in Session (HashTable is good option). When user moves back, fetch the value for that Question Id from Session. Refresh Session object whenever user moves to Next question. But remember to handle situation where - User moves back and then next again, the question Id is already in collection.